# Cannot read property 'address_components' of undefined while implementing Place autcomplete address form

Tags: javascript, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement Google Place Autocomplete Address Form on my website but I have some problems to.

Until now, I target the good input. When I click on, I see the alert to provide access to my position. When I type text in, google provides 5 addresses but when I click on one, nothing appends. For the moment, I only targeted the postal code and the city to be filled by Google.

I have the following error message :

> Cannot read property 'address_components' of undefined

Jquery is implemented and I wrote my key API in the  just like that :

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&libraries=places">
</script>
```

All of the following code is put inside a .js file :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let addressField = document.getElementById('dwfrm_profile_address_address1');
    let autocomplete;
    let componentForm = {
        dwfrm_profile_address_city: 'long_name',
        dwfrm_profile_address_postal: 'short_name'
    };


    addressField.addEventListener('focus', function () {
        geolocate()
    });

    addressField.addEventListener('blur', function () {
        initAutocomplete(addressField)
    });

    function initAutocomplete(addressField) {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
        // geographical location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            addressField, { types: ['geocode'] });

            // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
            // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
            autocomplete.setFields(['address_components']);

            // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
            // address fields in the form.
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress(autocomplete));
        }

        function fillInAddress(autocomplete) {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            for (var component in componentForm) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details,
            // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }
                    
        function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var geolocation = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({ 
                        center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy });
                    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        }
        initAutocomplete();
        fillInAddress();
        geolocate();
    });
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a check, because you do not know on when you are going to get the places from google. so you need to check first if there before you iterate.

```
if (place) {
 // you code here
}
```